# when make a cross-platform c++ GIS core, how to make the 2d-drawing platform independent?

Tags: c++, display, 2d

i try to develop a c++ no-GUI GIS core(i want the core have no GUI related things, do not use any GUI library)  and  I can figure out how to do other things except the drawing part.  when cope with 2D drawing, it must assign the drawing context, so it could not be platform-independent? For example , in windows, i need get the handle of  DC. So i think always the 2D-drawing is related to platform.

how could i make the drawing things platform- independent? any one have some advises?

Comment: I don't think the "GIS" part holds any bearing over the "cross-platform drawing stack" part of your problem. You may want to ask this on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Cross-platform GUIs for C++ programs are typically developed using Qt these days.